# PHP - Как отфильтровать массивы по конкретному значению

Tags: php

Хочу отфильтровать массивы. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Есть такой массив, который выводится с помощью переменной - $Myitems

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Pencil
            [color] => Blue
            [material] => Wood
            [size] => XL
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Pen
            [color] => Red
            [material] => Plastic
            [size] => XXL
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Pencil
            [color] => Green
            [material] => Wood
            [size] => L
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Pen
            [color] => Blue
            [material] => Plastic
            [size] => M
        )

)
```

Мне нужно сделать так чтобы выводились только те массивы, в которых есть значение "Blue". Чтобы по итогу я получил это:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Pencil
            [color] => Blue
            [material] => Wood
            [size] => XL
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Pen
            [color] => Blue
            [material] => Plastic
            [size] => M
        )

)
```

Сюда стараюсь обращаться только в крайнем случае и он настал. Перелопатил кучу статей, но даже близко не могу найти как это решить. Возможно я не правильно строю поисковые запросы. Помогите пожалуйста это решить.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php

Comment: "Возможно я не правильно строю поисковые запросы" --- ну вот задача у вас...... PHP, массивы, отфильтровать данные (слово отфильтровать у вас присутствует в заголовке)....... неужели в поисковике ничего не выдало? Вот у меня первая же ссылка

Comment: Думаете, если было бы все так просто, я бы писал сюда? Из Мануала пример мне не подходит. Мне в другом месте подсказали куда смотреть. Тоже Array Filter, но есть свою нюансы. Я уже сумел более менее встать на нужный путь. Как добью решение, выложу его сюда.

Comment: "Из Мануала пример мне не подходит" --- почему?

Comment: "Думаете, если было бы все так просто, я бы писал сюда?" --- конечно))) подобных сообщений каждый день минимум десяток прилетает.  И это только в тех темах, которые я отслеживаю. А есть ещё 100 меток, которые я не отслеживаю. Соответственно подобных сообщений ещё гораздо больше

Comment: Я не PHP специалист, чтобы объяснить почему. Я выложу завтра рабочее решение, и вы увидите разницу.

Comment: "Я не PHP специалист, чтобы объяснить почему." --- ну вы же сказали "не подходит", значит вы знаете *почему*, что-то же не устроило, не удовлетворило, Или вы так, просто брякнули?

Comment: Не подходит потому что не работает. Вообще не работает. Не надет результат. Ничего не происходит, когда его применяю. Как вам еще объяснить?)))

Comment: Ну так покажи код который не работает. Мы ж тут не телепатим сидим.

Comment: Надо не код из примера копировать слепо, а прочитать саму документацию по функции: что она принимает и что нужно описать внутри и согласно своей логике применить эти знания ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  Т.к. внутри логика может быть разная, согласно задаче

Comment: Помогли в англ. ветке. Рабочий код опубликовал ниже. 'Надо не код из примера копировать слепо...' — если бы для меня это было так просто, то я бы не писал сюда вопрос. Я не занимаюсь программированием каждый день, поэтому и обратился за помощью. Интересное наблюдение: у русскоязычных программистов есть своя особенность, облить помоями и показать какой ты дурак, вместо того, чтобы помочь.

Comment: Вам дали ссылку на документацию, это называется облить помоями и сказать что дурак? ну тогда вам можно не приходить на ресурс больше, раз вы **ТАК** всё воспринимаете.......... и да..... код в вопросе   с применением **той самой функции, ссылку на которую я дал**......но вы умеете только копипастить, видимо. а не читать доки и писать сам

Comment: Я разве не с самого начала сказал, что не нашел готового решения, поэтому детально описал задачу здесь с просьбой о помощи? И что эту документацию уже видел, и она для меня бесполезна? Какой смысл по сто раз отсылать к ней? Повторю еще раз: Я не программист и не собираюсь им быть. С этим каждый день я не работаю. Возникла небольшая проблема, по которой нанимать отдельно программиста не имеет смысла. Что такое php.net я знаю, и когда нужно туда заглядываю. Но это не всегда помогает понять проблему и найти решение.

Comment: "Я разве не с самого начала сказал, что не нашел готового решения" --- нет. ничего такого упомянуто не было.......... "готовые решения" - это на  freelance.ru ...........у данного ресурса другие задачи, нежели выполнение заказов.......кто делает - просто за репой гонится, а не "добрейшей души человек"......остальное лирика..... когда "заказчик" или не программер сам роет код - потом становится всё хуже и хуже и никто уже не захочет в этой куче *** потом копаться...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге это задача была решена так:

```
$make = 'Blue'; //Значение ключа по которому фильтруем массивы
$Myfilter = array_filter($Myitems, function($Myitems) use($make) {
    return $Myitems['color'] === $make;
});
```

Далее в шаблоне выводим данные этого массива:

```
<?php foreach($Myfilter as $mylist) : ?>
//Выводим значения массива
<?php endforeach; ?>
```